# Single quote inside double quote is messing up javascript code

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, django

I'm building a Django web app and I'm trying to send a JSON object to my javascript code using a Django template variable.

```py
# views.py

import json

def get_autocomplete_cache():
   autocomplete_list = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4 - don't delete"]
   return json.dumps(autocomplete_list)
```

```html
<!-- html page -->
<script>
   // Things i've tried

   autocomplete = {{ autocomplete_list|safe }};
   autocomplete = '{{ autocomplete_list|safe }}';
   autocomplete = JSON.parse('{{ autocomplete_list|safe }}');
</script>
```

If I wrap `{{ autocomplete_list|safe }` in single quotes like `'{{ autocomplete_list|safe }}'`, then the single quote in `test4 - don't delete` messes up the variable and

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

However, if I leave it as `{{ autocomplete_list|safe }}`, then the HTML text highlights it as an error with red underlines. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know django or python, but `safe` in some other templating engines/languages does not encode single quotes but encode double-quotes. Try `autocomplete = "{{ autocomplete_list|safe }}";`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon When I do this, the engine thinks the first double quote in autocomplete_list is me trying to close the string, and it messes everything up.

Comment: @charlietfl This is some very very basic code mainly just to showcase what the data looks like on the back end and how I'm trying to load it in on the front-end. There's more to the story than just the code i'm showing, but it's irrelevant

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon What I mean is the variable ends up becoming `"["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4 - don't delete"]"` and the double quotes interact with the quotes in the strings.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code as I understand it you mean to use it in two variants (as below) and it works fine for me. Maybe if you post more detailed code it will be easier to figure out what is the problem.

```py
def view_1(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'autocomplete_list': ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4 - don't delete"]})

def view_2(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'autocomplete_list': json.dumps(["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4 - don't delete"])})
```

```html
<script>
    var autocomplete_list = {{ autocomplete_list|safe }};
</script>
```

You can try also `SafeString`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.safestring

```py
from django.utils.safestring import SafeString

def view(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'autocomplete_list': SafeString(autocomplete_list)})
```

And maybe `json-script` filter will works for you: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

usage:

```
{{ value|json_script:"hello-data" }}
```

output:

```
<script id="hello-data" type="application/json">{"hello": "world"}</script>
```

access in JS:

```
var value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);
```